# Can't use string ("Managers::Toke::Interface") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at line 47

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I'm building my first Perl constructor and I'm getting this error.

```
Can't use string ("Managers::Toke::Interface") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at
```

Here is my constructor.

```
package Managers::Toke::Interface;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Core::ReturnValue;
use Data::Dumper;

## Toke stands for "The Online Kilobyte Extractor"



sub new {

my( $class, $username, $useruuid, $bytesSent, $bytesReceived, $bytePosition ) = @_ ;

my $self = {
'username'=> $username,
'useruuid'=> $useruuid,
'bytesSent'=> $bytesSent,
'bytesReceived' => $bytesReceived,
'bytePosition' => $bytePosition,
'date'         => $date,
};

return bless $self, $class;
}


sub explain {
    my $self = shift;
    return sprintf "Hi, I'm %s", $self->{'username'};
}
```

Here is the program that is calling it:

```
my $return = Managers::Toke::Interface->new($username,
                                   $uuid,
                                   $receivedBytesToKB,
                                   $sentBytesToKB,
                                   $bytePosition) or die "$!";



$return = Managers::Toke::Interface->explain();
```

I'm hoping the answer is not obvious, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're misunderstanding some fundamental concepts about how OOP works.

Your constructor *constructs* an object and then returns it. The attributes that you spent all that time setting in your constructor are stored in the object. (The *instance* of the class you're creating.) But you throw away the object that you created and try to call an instance method on the class itself.

When you use the arrow (`->`) operator to call a method, the thing on the left side (the *invocant*) is passed into the method as the first parameter. That's why you can unpack it into `$class` in your constructor.

When you say

```
Managers::Toke::Interface->explain();
```

That's basically equivalent to

```
Managers::Toke::Interface::explain( 'Managers::Toke::Interface' );
```

You unpack that string into `$self` in your `explain` sub, then try to access it like it's a hash ref. Obviously that's not going to work. When you call an instance method, you have to call it on the object instance, which is usually a hashref that has been blessed, not the class.

```
my $object = Managers::Toke::Interface->new($username,
                               $uuid,
                               $receivedBytesToKB,
                               $sentBytesToKB,
                               $bytePosition) or die "$!";

$object->explain();
```

Now the code is equivalent to

```
Managers::Toke::Interface::explain( $object );
```

where `$object` is the thing you constructed in `new`, which *can* be used as a hashref, because it is one.

Check out the detailed [Perl OO Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html) for more, and then read the chapter on objects in [Modern Perl](http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl/chapter_07.html#toc_T2JqZWN0cw).

Comment: I'm looking for it? Do I have to wait 24hrs before I can check mark it?